# Induction Problem, showing one sequence is greater than the other.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

Need help proving $$\frac{4}{n} \geq \frac{2^n}{n!}$$ for all natural numbers $n$  using induction. I need help finding an inequality that situates itself between one another.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is induction compulsory?

Comment: It's not, but our professor gave it as a hint, its part of a problem to show that one sequence is greater than the other sequence, so I think he wants us to use induction.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$ we have
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}\geq\frac{2}{n+1}.
$$
Assume $\frac{4}{n}\geq\frac{2^n}{n!}$ for some $n>1$, then multiplying sides we get
$$
\frac{4}{n+1}\geq\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that trivial rearrangement makes this equivalent to showing $(n-1)! \geq 2^{n-2}\ \  \forall n \geq 2$. The $n=1$ case can be handled separately.

Note that $k!= k(k-1)! \geq 2\cdot(k-1)! \geq 2\cdot 2^{n-2} = 2^{k-1} \ \ \forall k\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since induction is not compulsory as you said:

For $n=1,2$ it is obvious.

For $n\geq 3$ you have
$$\frac{2^n}{n!}= \frac 21\cdot \underbrace{\frac{2\cdots 2}{2\cdots (n-1)}}_{\leq 1}\cdot \frac 2n\leq \frac 4n$$